# python determining name of the importing module

Tags: python, multithreading, import, names

How do you determine the name of the importing module within the module that is being imported.  I have the partial solution, but not the complete one.

The code is: 
A.py

```
import B

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'This a test'
```

The B.py

```
import sys
import C
if sys.argv[0] == 'A':
    doSomething()
```

At this point, I'm all set because within module B, I know that name of the main that invoked the importing which in this case is A.  However, within B, an import of C is requested, and it is in C that I want to know whether B imported C? How is this done?

Comment: Would you mind sharing a bit of background as to why you want to do this?

Comment: Jon, I have a project and I'm using a team built library.  Within the library is an import of a module that crashes with a path problem.  My intention was to add one line of code in the library that says, if myProject is importing this module, then don't import this module that crashes because I have no use for it anyway.  I have just been informed that my request is ill-defined since python imports a module only once, so this scheme may not be robust.

Answer (score 2):

`sys.argv[0]` is not a name of module when `import` was performed. This is name of executable file.

On the other side, inside Python module `__name__` equals to a) module name if it's executed by importing, b) `"__main__"` if it was executed as script.

Module doesn't "know" who performed `import` (no "parent" attribute or something like this). Define your behavior with different functions and call them from different modules.

Comment: +1 for "Define your behavior with different functions and call them from different modules."

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is actually what you want to do, however. Note, in particular, that the top-level code in B will only run once, no matter how many times the module is imported from however many places.

For example, if you also import module D somewhere which imports module C before module B gets to, then your code in C for when it is imported from B will never run.

I think it is probably a better idea to simply define a function in C which B can run once after having imported C.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [interpreter-stack](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack) or [traceback](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html). Both will give you the stack's function calls, so this is not exactly the solution you want (modules).